# How to evaluate a tables in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table, lua-patterns, luainterface, lua-scripting-library

Hi guys I could really use some help. I'm not a programmer I'm just started out

Im trying to store every resulting calculated value of two tables and somehow store it into another table for later use.

```
Close = {1,2,6,2,2,...8} --livedata with a series of value upto 100
Open = {3,10,1,5,3,...10}--livedata with series of value upto 100
```

So here's my code

```
body = {}
  For i = 1,100 do
    if close[i] > open[i] then
      V = close[i] - open[i] 
    else
      V = open[i] - close[i]
    end
      table.insert(body,1,V)
   end

for k,v in pairs(body) do print(k,v) end
```

Here's the result

```
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    2
100  2
```

It just keep repeating it last calculated value for a 100 times

I'd expect it the result to be something like this

```
1  2
2  8
3  5
4  3
5  1
100 2
```

Really appreciate it anyone who  help

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. After fixing the code so it actually runs, I get a variety of values in `body`, not just 2.

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing the exact code you're running (as the variables have different names and `For` should be lowercase), but the main issue seems to be with the `table.insert` call (`table.insert(body,1,V)`), as you're always inserting in the first position, so you're results have the reversed order. If you fix these issues (just use `table.insert(body,V)`), you should get the expected results.